# Display text in columns in listbox?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and I have to do a task of creating a GUI. It works fine, but I wonder how I should do to present text inside of a listbox. My first thought was to just add each textpiece with a plus sign to a new string. But since on of the string is a name and could be short or long names, it's not looking good. So I wonder if there is a way to show each string in some column or how is this done best? Preciate some tips! Thanks!

Rows of columns I was thinking of:

```
Number   Name  Adress  City
```

Comment: WinForms/Wpf/ASP.NET? - most of them have a multi column list box option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ListBox.MultiColumn Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx) might help.

Comment: I believe so, please check the sample link above.

Comment: Yes it look like it will work. I have to try a bit later. Thanks!